# location.href from JavaScript not working on iOS 13.4 PWA (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, ios13

I did write a PWA in Angular 6 which uses `location.href=mailto...` inside the ts-file and runs on iOS.

Since Customers updated they're IPads to iOS 13.4 `location.href=mailto:` is not working anymore in the PWA Mode, but still works fine in the Browser (Safari).

Is there a workaround to get it working again in PWA Mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.location.href = "mailto:address@gmail.com";
},500);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The Browser asks if the E-Mail App should be opened but if i press "yes", nothing happens.

I found workaround: If i use mailto as html-tag on a button, it works fine. So i have to pre-write the E-Mail every time when the Data changes. As the the E-Mail button has been hit, the data ist already prepared and can be acessed as a property... 
Computed properties for Angular would have been very nice.